# Need help regarding OpenVPN & Squid3 proxy server

Tags: networking, debian, proxy, openvpn

[The network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OQtS.png)

The proxy server is set to only allow traffic from a certain IP network (192.168.100.0/24 from DHCP server) to pass and only allow access to certain websites in the Apache server that are whitelisted.

I have an OpenVPN server in another machine (Server PC) next to the proxy server's (Router PC), which spits out it's own DHCP IP (10.8.0.4/30) to connected clients. So my client computer has 2 interface and 2 IP, one that's connected to the router PC and has IP from DHCP server (192.168.100.0/24), and a TAP interface with OpenVPN's IP (10.8.0.6/30).

As per my knowledge, when I send request to open a website in my Apache2 server, OpenVPN encrypts the packet going out and is using it's own IP to send those packets (hiding the original IP).

My question is how does the request gets through Squid, despite not having the IP that is allowed (it's using the VPN's IP of 10.8.0.4/30 instead of 192.168.100.0/24) in the proxy setting, yet the proxy still works and blocks the non-whitelist website?

P.S. It's for a final exam in my Vocabulary School in Network & Computer Engineering, and it is not mentioned whether the OpenVPN supposed to be installed in the Server PC or Router PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As per my knowledge, when I send request to open a website in my Apache2 server, OpenVPN encrypts the packet going out and is using it's own IP to send those packets (hiding the original IP).

I feel a great misunderstanding here. OpenVPN does not intercept traffic or anything. It appears on your computer as a regular network interface with an IP address and all. Only traffic that leaves over this virtual network interface is sent over the encrypted VPN connection.

So, how is traffic directed over the VPN interface? With regular routing. On Windows, you could use `route print` to inspect the routing table. Unless you set something up (e.g. using OpenVPN’s `redirect-gateway` option), only traffic to `10.8.0.4/30` (likely an effect of `topology net30`) will use the VPN connection.

If OpenVPN is configured with `redirect-gateway def1`, you still have a more specific route going to the Squid host. Contacting anything in `192.168.100.0/24` will simply not use the VPN.

Comment: My OpenVPN configuration uses the `push "redirect-gateway"` option, does that mean that it won't redirect the outgoing traffic to somewhere in 192.168.100.0/24 to use the VPN tunnel?

Comment: No, it won’t. Unless the `block-local` flag is specified for `redirect-gateway`, local LAN connectivity is not affected at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation & information! That traffic intercept bit really set things straight in my mind

Comment: Oh one more thing, I put `push dhcp option DNS 10.10.100.1`, and without putting my local DNS server address (`10.10.100.1)` there, I can't seem to be a able to access my apache server nor nslookup on its domain. How can it affect the client resulting in client not being able to reach the web server, when the web server location itself `(192.168.100.0/24)` has nothing to do with the tunnel interface of OpenVPN `(10.8.0.4/30)`?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what DNS is used when you don’t specify one with OpenVPN. Presumably, it is outside the local network and some configuration error on the OpenVPN server prevents your computer from reaching it over the VPN connection.